# How to create dynamic maps in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to make a map interface like the one in this one: http://www.developmentcheck.org
Can somebody please give me idea where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by looking at the google maps documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

and the tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

This will give you enough to get started, and when you find specific issues there are lots of existing questions here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

take a look at that first
[Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

it will help you